# How to stop a Page from auto-scrolling UP on Mobile devices? (using Blogger template)

Tags: javascript, android, blogger

My website is: https://www.breastactivesfunciona.com/ which is based on the Blogger Dynamic Views “Mosaic” template. (I have set the template to display Desktop view on Mobile devices).

The Problem: On Android devices, on an open page, when I scroll down the page and when I come to footer, the page jumps instantly right to the testimonials section.

I would be most grateful if someone would suggest a solution to stop a Page auto-scrolling to the top, on Android devices. (I very much like the Mosaic template, so I am reluctant to change to another template. However as it stands the template is not really usable due to this auto-scrolling issue).

For better understanding check this video: https://streamable.com/ubx4r6